# Automated tool to create an Openstack Cloud

Tags: server, openstack, cloud, automation

i'd like to work with Openstack and wanted to deploy a small cloud to get started.
My idea is to have a 2 servers infrastructure: 1 controller node and 1 compute node connected on a private LAN.
I'd like to use an automated tool to deploy the cloud; something "easy" where you only need to say this server is the compute while this one is the controller (no storage or other)

I found something like that: Red Hat Openstack where a third server, acting as a director, creates and install Openstack on the cloud nodes.
Anyhow, I'd like to avoid working with something requiring licenses and adding a 3rd server.

I'd prefer something with no licensing, maybe on top of Ubuntu server to create this simple 2 server topology.

Does anyone have a possible solution?
Thanks in advance
Umberto

Answer (score 1):

Canonical offers **Openstack Autopilot**, which is free for use up to 10 nodes.  However, it requires a minimum of 5 servers using CEPH/CEPH.  If you change CEPH to Swift for object storage, I believe it requires 7 servers.

1. MAAS
2. Landscape
3. Network Node
4. Compute Node
5. Compute Node

At this time, I am unaware of a ubuntu openstack deployment tool that would automate the process for you and use less hardware.  You can configure the stack manually and get away with the setup you want with less hardware.

Comment: You don't need to use real-world servers to learn how to work with OpenStack, virtual machines or lxc containers residing on your main workstation are likely much more convenient to set up while you're learning. When it comes time to deploy, and you only have two servers to dedicate to the task, again use virtual machines or system containers to get the node count you need and portion out your resources.

`conjure-up` is also freely available in the repos